Rtl support for drawableEnd of AppCompatEditText Android
I am using this AppCompatEditText like this
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilCountry"
                        style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dpSixteen"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dpSixteen"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dpTwenty"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/chooseCountry"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
                        app:hintTextColor="@color/moonRaker">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                            android:id="@+id/etCountry"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_blue_right"
                            android:drawableTint="@color/blue"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/SignupEditText"
                            tools:targetApi="m" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

when user change the language to arabic every thing looks fine with rtl but
drawableEnd not changing from right to left.


Arrow must switch to left side when arabic selected with mirror effect.
my drawable code
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="7.41dp"
    android:height="12dp"
    android:viewportWidth="7.41"
    android:viewportHeight="12"
    **android:autoMirrored="true"**>
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,10.58 L4.58,6 0,1.41 1.41,0l6,6 -6,6Z"
      android:fillColor="#1b47db"/>
</vector>

What is wrong here?

Did you include android:supportsRtl="true" within the  tag in your manifest file? For more details, you can refer to the official documentation here:  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#MirroringManifest

yes this tag is already added

I found the solution :-
I just give the layout direction to my parent xml layout like this
public static void rtlConversion(Activity activity, String lang, View view) {
    int layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR; // default to LTR
    if (lang != null && (lang.equals(ARABIC_CODE) || lang.equals(URDU_CODE))) {
      layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
    }
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(layoutDirection);
    if (view != null) {
      view.setLayoutDirection(layoutDirection);
      view.requestLayout();
      view.invalidate();
    }
  }

By doing this every view in the that layout will adjust the rtl and ltr by it's own. like icon mirroring, text alignment etc..
Even I think this line is also not needed.

activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(layoutDirection);

because I use material.textfield.TextInputLayout
it has these four property in layoutDirection
<attr name="layoutDirection">
            <!-- Left-to-Right. -->
            <enum name="ltr" value="0" />
            <!-- Right-to-Left. -->
            <enum name="rtl" value="1" />
            <!-- Inherit from parent. -->
            <enum name="inherit" value="2" />
            <!-- Locale. -->
            <enum name="locale" value="3" />
</attr>


Defines the direction of layout drawing. This typically is associated
with writing
direction of the language script used. The possible values are "ltr" for Left-to-Right,
"rtl" for Right-to-Left, "locale", and "inherit" from parent view. If there is nothing
to inherit, "locale" is used. "locale" falls back to "en-US". "ltr" is the direction
used in "en-US". The default for this attribute is "inherit".

So with this default inherit property, views can adjust the layoutDirection from parent layout.
By doing this... I think proper rtl ltr UI we can handle.
If you got a simpler solution? Let me know!

Drawable should be set from the start if the language is Arabic, otherwise, it should be set from the end.
android:textDirection="anyRtl"

try this way

we don't need to do it manually.
when we change the layout direction it automatically adjust all this things.

android:textDirection="rtl"
try it

No!
this is fixed for arabic or urdu... what if user select english language.
I asked for dynamic solution

see updated answer

did you check by this icon mirroring and switching to left side is working??? when user select the Arabic language?

bro, have you checked? after adding this line. because this is working properly from my side.
